# how to check multiple conditon while sending email in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

i have user model that contains user `email`. 
another model `project` that has one to many association with `stage`. stage has a attribute `remind_at`. now i want to send mail to only people whose role is `manager` and `stage.remind_at == Time.now`. how can i achieve this goal in this method??

```
  def activity_reminder(stage)
    @stage = stage
      mail(:to =>  User.where(role: 'manager').pluck(:email), :subject => "Project Activity Remainder")
  end
```

current method sends mail to all user whose role is `manager`

Comment: What's the relationship between user and stage?

Comment: @SebastianPalma there is relation b/w user and project. one to many association b/w user and project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that with the actual relationships you could do something like this:

```
User.joins(projects: :stages).where(role: 'manager', stages: { remind_at: Time.now }).pluck(:email)
```